low collision hash function for unordered lists
Suppose I have a list of 64-bit integers $X = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)$.
I want to make a hash signature for $X$ with a very low collision rate, preferably one as low as the SHA functions.
The catch is that the signature has to be independent of the order of the elements of the list.  For example, hash(1,2,3,4), hash(4,1,3,2) and hash(1,4,3,2) must be equal.
A solution is to sort $X$ then calculate SHA256 of the sorted list. However, the number of elements $N$ may be too large; the integers come in a stream and there may be too many to store.
If the elements of the list were small (say 8 or 16 bits), we could just count how many times each value occurs and hash the resulting table.  Can't do that with 64-bits.
Order-independent hash functions exist, for example the sum, but I didn't think of anything that is likely to have a very low collision rate.
It's easy to make up functions that are hard to find collisions for, but I want something that has a good case for being genuinely strong.
A superficially similar question was asked before, but it is not a dup of this question as it does not mention two of the key requirements of my question, namely infinitesimal collision rate and online applicability.

Even though the responses are unsuitable, the question is still a dupe.

Does this answer your question? Order insensitive hash function for an array

This question and its answers and comments also addresses your problem: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54544/676

A crude choice might be to combine two bad choices each with too many collisions in the hope that their weaknesses are different. Sum{elements} XOR {elements} for example. I think you basically have to accept some collisions whenever you hash. Experimenting to find the rule with an acceptable rate with your data might be the only way. It is really a maths question rather than a programming one.

@LeviRamsey, that's the question I linked to and it is not the same question, as the needs of a hash table are vastly easier.  However, the answer at crypto.se that President found looks adaptable to my case and I'm studying it. A large multiplication for each element will be expensive, but maybe that's the price one has to pay.
